# Between Math and Sql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me to answer this question..

if I have database, table name is table1 and the field name is example its contain 5 numbers like this:

```
example
1
2
3
4
5
```

then I would like do this with database above:

```
1*2 = 2
3*2 = 6
4*6 = 24
5*24 = 120
120 * 10% = 12
```

What is the correct sql query to make that happen?

thank you very much

Comment: Where are you getting the second set of numbers from ?

Comment: Where are the other numbers coming from?

Comment: What programming language did you use , bash?

Comment: Looks like he is just multiplying by 2 on the first one, then taking the product and using that to multiply the next one, and so on.  Then taking 10% of the final product .....  very confusing.

Comment: Is percent depends of number of rows or it is always 10?

Comment: yes you are correct Mr. samuel Jackson

Comment: it always 10% MikkaRin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user-defined variables in you query ,if multiplication result exceeds from 100 and you need to divide it by 10 you can do so

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(example,'*',@mul) `expression`,
@mul := CASE 
WHEN @mul* example >100 
THEN (@mul* example/10) 
ELSE @mul* example END
mul
FROM  Table1,
(SELECT @mul:=1) p
ORDER BY `example`
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6af817/5)

For your exactly the same desired result set this would work

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
CONCAT(example,'*',@mul) `expression`,
@mul := @mul* example mul
FROM  Table1,
(SELECT @mul:=1) p
 ORDER BY `example`
) t
UNION
SELECT  CONCAT(@mul,'*',' 10% ') `expression`,
(@mul/10) FROM (SELECT @mul) p1
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6af817/11)